# how to delete a tkinter window using lambda with a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing a project that uses many tkinter buttons on different windows and I want to be able to close a window and run a function at the same time using lambda but the window doesn't close. If I stop using lambda it works again. I tried in repl and in idle but got the same result. This works:

```
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('500x300')

def function():
  print('hi')

btn = Button(tk, text='hi', command = tk.destroy)
btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

but this doesn't:

```
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
tk.geometry('500x300')

def function():
  print('hi')

btn = Button(tk, text='hi', command = lambda:[ function(),tk.destroy])
btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

why?

Comment: not good practice to use lists and therefore call multiple functions when using `lambda`, define a separate function to call both of those functions, also the reason that the second doesn't work is because You are not calling the function, You just pass the function object to the lambda function

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either 

import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the 

whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth 

like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; 

name clashes are the issue.

Comment: @Theawesometurtl if You are creating multiple windows You shouldn't use `Tk` instances for those, instead use `Toplevel` to create new windows, if You wanted to close all of them, You probably would have to append each of them to a list or sth and then destroy using a for loop

Comment: ok, I'll try to keep your advice in mind, thanks

Comment: better create normal functiona with `hello.hi(), tk. destroy()` - and assing `command=function`. it will be more readable for all people.

Comment: your class seems useless - you could create directly function `hi()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
btn = Button(tk, text='hi', command = lambda:[ hello.hi(),tk.destroy])
```

use:

```
btn = Button(tk, text='hi', command = lambda:[hello.hi(),tk.destroy()])
```

and it should work.

Comment: but actually You shouldn't call multiple functions with lambda at all, bad practice